# How to fetch tweets of a given user?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to use the Twitter API in order to automatically fetch the last tweet of a given user, but I'm having trouble :/

I am using this library : https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

I installed it, everything seems working, but when I try to fetch the timeline of a user, I only get all my timeline :(

Here is my code:

```
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='***', consumer_secret='****', access_token_key='***', access_token_secret='****')
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline('@twitterapi')
print [s.text for s in statuses]
```

Is there something I missed ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove '@' from the first parameter of `GetUserTimeline` (i.e. `api.GetUserTimeline('twitterapi')`) ?

Comment: Yes, same result :/ and when I try to use the id instead of the user name, I got an erro saying that the user doesn't exist :/

Comment: What happens if you only use `api = twitter.Api()`? I think you do not need api-keys for public tweets.

Comment: No, I got this error: twitter.TwitterError: [{u'message': u'Bad Authentication data', u'code': 215}]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to provide the userId rather than the screen_name in order for the GetUserTimeLine to work.

Also, although you might expect that this would return the equivalent of that user's home status page, it does not. Instead, it returns just the tweets from that user.

The twitter API documentation mentions another method - GetFriendsTimeline, but, despite being listed in the documentation, it doesn't seem to exist as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly enter `screen_name=` or `user_id=` otherwise the value defaults to the authenticated user.

**Examples:**

```
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name='some_handle')
```

or

```
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(user_id=22233344)
```